# Browser Choice with Automation Test in Python

Tags: python, unit-testing, selenium

Initially I have def setup() with options to call specific web browsers from another file that have all the information on how to setup the web browser. Remarking out the browser not used.

```
    def setUp(self):
    # Choose the Web Browser to test with
    operabrowser(self)
    # chromebrowser(self)
   ...

def test_one()
    ...
def test_two()
    ...
```

I am trying to move away from editing the test file each time, I am looking to setup a console input that will call the browser and I have added to def setup().

```
    browser_choice = input ( """Choose your browser
    Opera, [Firefox], Chrome or Safari
    > """ ).lower ()
    if browser_choice == 'opera':
        operabrowser()
    else chromebrowser()
```

This works with a single unit test but if there is more than one test in the file it asks each time for a browser choice.

How can I get this option to be asked only once for all tests that will be ran in the test file? I have tried a few other ways of approaching this all unsuccessful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tests should be defined as class methods, in your code they appears to be standalone functions not directly related with the class which holds the `setUp()` method. You just need to modify your code like this:

```
import unittest

class YouTests(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        q = 'Choose your browser Opera, [Firefox], Chrome or Safari >'
        browser_choice = input (q).lower ()
        if browser_choice == 'opera':
            operabrowser()
        else: 
            chromebrowser()

    def test_one(self):
        pass

    def test_two(self):
        pass

...
```

If you have multiple classes inheriting from `unittest.TestCase` and all should use the same browser the browser choice will be best inserted in your `global` scope. For example:

```
browser_object = None
...

def operabrowser():
    global browser_object
    # Init opera object here

def chromebrowser():
    global browser_object
    # Init chrome object here

...
# Your tests using the browser_object
...

if __name__ == '__main__':
    q = 'Choose your browser Opera, [Firefox], Chrome or Safari >'
    browser_choice = input (q).lower ()
    if browser_choice == 'opera':
        operabrowser()
    elif browser_choice == 'firefox':
        ...
    else: 
        chromebrowser()

    unittest.main()
```

Comment: I have what you added currently in my file thanks, this is just a snippet of what I am trying to achieve. I am trying to add in the second code snippet into the setup without it calling for the input of browser choice for each unit test. The actual test file is hundreds of unit tests.

Comment: @VCHealy I've updated the answer to address your comment. Please check if it solves your issue.

Comment: Thanks I have added the above, tweaked it a little and moved the browser choices into a separate file and import them. It makes it easier for maintenance. The browser opens, the url accessed and the user login accepted. Unfortunately the actual unit tests don't run. The tests is nothing special other than a few element clicks

Comment: @VCHealy I know you are new to stackoverflow, but you should vote and accept the answer if it had solved your question. Good luck!

Comment: I pressed the button but it says I can't publicly register it yet. Although the choice of browser settings works with your suggestions, the actual tests do not run with this solution.